# java similar function with different condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I have a set of functions defined like this:

```
public void foo1(int a, int b){
    if (a > b){
        c++;
    }
}


public void foo2(int a, int b){
    if (a > b && b = 7){
        c++;
    }
}


public void foo3(int a, int b){
    if (a >= b){
        c++;
    }
}
```

Which only differ in their conditions for a and b. Is there a way to contain these as one function, where I can set the condition as a variable? Or something similar?

EDIT: Please note this is a trivial example, I want to know if it's possible to pass a condition to a function

Comment: you meant JavaScript? if so, please change the tag.

Comment: In java method definition does not start with `function` it looks like `public void foo(Type t1, Type t2)`.

Comment: Yes I know, typed quickly on the fly. Doesn't effect the question at all, but updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a general solution, you can define an interface:

```
public interface Predicate {
    public boolean eval(int a, int b);
}
```

Then define your function:

```
public void foo(Predicate predicate, int a, int b) {
    if (predicate.eval(a, b)) {
        c++;
    }
}
```

Then you can define various `Predicate` objects:

```
Predicate test1 = new Predicate() {
    @Override
    public boolean eval(int a, int b) {
        return a >= b;
    }
};
// etc.
```

and pass whichever one is appropriate to `foo()`.

Alternatively, you can look at making use of the [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface using `Boolean` as the type parameter. (It can't take arguments, however, so it doesn't exactly fit your pattern.)

Answer (score 2):

You can have one function like this that combines all of the conditions:

```
public void foo(int a, int b) {
    if (a >= b && b == 7) {
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a trivial example, sorry. I mean is there a way to pass a condition to the function?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that came to mind is actually

```
public void foo(int a, int b, boolean condition){
    if (condition){
        c++;
    }
}
```

The call will "look like" passing a condition:

```
foo( a, b, a>b );
foo( a, b, a > b && b = 7 );
foo( a, b, a>=b );
```

You're actually passing the result of the conditional test, but in many cases that is good enough.

Just adding it here because it's simple and no one else seemed to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

@Nikhar is right, one thing that you can do to solve your confusion while dealing with this is using the OR operator like this

```
function foo( int a, int b ) {
 if ( ( a > b ) || (a > b && b = 7) || (a >= b) ) // if any of the condition is true then
    c++;  // increment it
}
```

Comment: @Ted I'm new to stack overflow, how did you changed this code area

Comment: To format code blocks, indent 4 spaces. You can also just highlight it and click on the `{}` button. (You can find out about all this by clicking on the `?` button above the top right of the edit area.)

Answer (score 0):

you can have an interface like

```
public interface MyCondn{
  boolean check(int a, int b);
}
```

Then,

```
public void foo(MyCondn cond, int a, int b){

   if(cond.check(a,b))
      c++;
}
```

You can define the conditions as

```
public class Foo1 implements MyCondn{
   boolean check(int a, int b){
      return a > b;
   }
}
```

And then,

```
classInsatnce.foo(new Foo1(), a,  b);
```

Comment: +0 You have plagiarized Ted's answer

Comment: @Bohemian given your rep, I would assume you know that people may write answers simultaneously. And, you must be unaware of the meaning of plagiarized. I did not copy, and your way of speaking needs an improvement. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Passing functions as parameters (predicates, in this case) will be easy to implement once Java gets lambdas, until now they *can* be implemented using anonymous inner functions, which are very verbose. For example, what you're asking could be implemented in a type-safe, generic way like this:

```
public class Test {

    private int c = 0;

    public void foo(Predicate<Integer, Integer> pred) {
        if (pred.condition()) {
            c++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();
        int a = 10;
        int b = 7;

        t.foo(new Predicate<Integer, Integer>(a, b) {
            @Override
            public boolean condition() {
                return a > b;
            }
        });

        t.foo(new Predicate<Integer, Integer>(a, b) {
            @Override
            public boolean condition() {
                return a > b && b == 7;
            }
        });

        t.foo(new Predicate<Integer, Integer>(a, b) {
            @Override
            public boolean condition() {
                return a >= b;
            }
        });

    }

}

abstract class Predicate<S, T> {
    S a;
    T b;
    Predicate(S a, T b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public abstract boolean condition();
}
```